# Import data from excel to table in sql

Tags: sql-server-2012, import, excel

Please I have issue that when I try to import data from excel to table in SQL it fails with below errors even I modified all the tables in the tables to be nvarchar(max) and I tried to enter dummy data in the first row

[image]

Comment: Would highly recommend saving as tab or pipe delimited, and using the flat file source. Otherwise, you can try updating the registry entry which controls the number of lines that the driver will scan in the Excel file to determine the length of the field. By default, it's only like the first 20 lines (don't quote me). Also, would recommend not using a $ sign in your table name. You can change it right in the import wizard.

Comment: I tried but didn't work correctly because there is Arabic inputs so it gives me question marks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked correctly for me with the below

1- Convert from XLSX to XLS

2- Add incremental primary key at XLS sheet

2- Then save as text Unicode

3- Go to Microsoft SQL then right click on the database then import flat file

4- Convert data types to nvarchar(max) if need it

Answer (score 0):

After importing the data from Excel you could change the `float` type to `decimal` and save the design of the table.

Then change `decimal` type to `nvarchar` and save the design again.

I have done this and it solved the problem for me.